# Alert if multi text found in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, find, alert

I have this code that alert if found a word, how can I make this work with multi words?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    
  setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Page loaded.");
      var LookFor = "HELLO"; // Text to find
        var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
        var hasText = content.indexOf(LookFor) !== -1;
        if(hasText) {
           console.log("Text fond!.");
          alert(Text fond)
      } else {
           console.log("Text not fond, reloading.");
            location.reload();
        }
   },3000);
});
```

I mean something like:

```
var LookFor = "HELLO","World","Fox","Number";
```

I try many way but don't work, anyone can help me?

Comment: Put it in an array: `var LookFor = ["HELLO","World","Fox","Number"];` and loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an array and do forEach like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    
  setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Page loaded.");
var lookFor = ["HELLO","World","Fox","Number"];
let foundChange = false;
lookFor.forEach(word => {

var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
        var hasText = content.indexOf(word) !== -1;
        if(hasText) { 
           foundChange = true;
           console.log("Text fond!.");
// This will alert only found words
          alert("Text found: " + word);
      }
});

// Only reload if no change was found
    if(!foundChange) {
        console.log("Text not fond, reloading.");
        location.reload();
    }
        
   },3000);
});
```

Comment: Work very fine! Thanks a lot!! I have a question more, how can show in alert the name of the text found: alert("hasText fond") not work

Comment: @RafaelYépez  `hasText` is a boolean if you want to alert the name of the text found write `alert(word)` . Please mark the answer as accepted if it works

Comment: word show me all wort and not the word found

Comment: @RafaelYépez you need to write it inside the `if(hasText)` statement. Please check the updated code

Comment: The script work fine but after found text still refreshing, never stop refreshing.

Comment: `location.reload()` is what makes it reload why do you need that line at all?

Comment: I'm making a telegram bot that notifie me when page add something, I set it using greasemonkey. I need the page reload for check changes and when the change show send a alert to telegram but if it not stop it will send a alert in each reload.

Comment: @RafaelYépez I modified the code so that the page only reloads when none of the search text was found